# SwipeRefreshLayout Stuck

Tags: android, swiperefreshlayout

I have a bit of a problem with my SwipeRefreshLayout,
Basically it does refresh the page, however, the animation is stuck.

On my refresh I call Asynctask of other class, so I guess there is a problem there.

My SwipeRefresh Listener :

```
swipeRefresh.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            MyClassAdapter.updateChallenges();
            MyClassAdapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            swipeRefresh.setRefreshing(false);
        }
    });
```

My Asynctask :

```
protected MyClass[] doInBackground(String... param) {
    URL oracle;
    BufferedReader in;
    String inputLine;
    String jsonFile = "";

    try {
        Thread.sleep(4000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        oracle = new URL("someURL");
        in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(oracle.openStream()));
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            jsonFile += inputLine;
        }
        in.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return jsonToStructure(jsonFile);
}
```

XML :

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/swipe_to_refresh"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

And as I said, the Adapter does refresh, but the animation of the swipeRefreshLayout is stuck.

P.S : I Added the Thread.sleep(4000) just to see if it can run parallel,
However what it does is just wait till the task finish, which is 4 second, then go off...

Do you guys have any idea for it?
Thanks you

Comment: You mean the whole animation stuck? Can you give more details about it? Any problem during the pull animation?

Comment: Well, it goes like this basically :
I swipe down my page,
See the loading circle on top of the page,
it does not animate (doesn't spin),
Job Finished,
it disappear (cause of the "swipeRefresh.setRefreshing(false);")

Comment: can you also show your xml layout? It seems that you don't have any scrollable view inside swipetorefresh

Comment: added, 
only scrollable views can be swipe to refresh?

Answer (score 0):

This might be a "Scrolling Conflict" issue, check the **onInterceptTouchEvent()** and **dispatchTouchEvent()** in your parent view.

SwipeRefreshLayout stuck, that's because of your swipeRefreshLayout can't get the touchEvent, or they dispatch the touch event to the child view, that's why it stuck.

This might help, check this: [Android Developer - Manage touch events in a ViewGroup](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/viewgroup#java)